# MySQL database Int overflow and can’t login in

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database on my server and I"m pretty sure it's an int over flow on one table with an auto_increment field that's crashing it.

I can delete the table, it's not very important, but I can't get into the server.

Is there anyway to delete that database from the file system or without logging into MySQL?

HELP! THE WORLD IS ENDING!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your `MySQL` is installed from a package, just go to `/var/lib/mysql` (or something like that, not sure what distro you are running). You will see a bunch of folders. Those folders have your table files in them. You can just more the one thats not working outside of `/var/lib/mysql`. Just stop `MySQL` before you do that.

Comment: It's a windows 2008 box.  Should I just delete the directory with the offending database?

Comment: You don't have to delete it, just move it out of that folder.

Comment: That killed the server.  Had to move back to a snap shot after I deleted the file.

Comment: MySQL server? Did you stop it before removing the directory? I have done it many times before, and never experienced a single issue. I suppose something is different with Windows version of MySQL....